# Decompiler issue "Could not find or load main class classes.dex"

Tags: java, android, decompiler

Attempting to recover an app I wrote not long ago (do not store in DropBox), I unzipped my .apk and tried to use

```
d2j-dex2jar classes.dex
```

to get my source, but got this message instead:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class classes.dex
```

Like all rookies, my main activity (only one, actually) was named MainActivity.java, not Main.java.  Is this the source of this error and if so, how can I fix it?  If not, what else can I try?

NOTE: this is being done in the DOS cmd window.

EDIT:  wow, nobody has ever seen this?

EDIT: I did not use ProGuard (I checked).

Comment: Did you use ProGuard?

Comment: No.  I'm a hobbyist, not a pro.  :)

Comment: Now that I think about it, I may have inadvertently done so.  If it is the standard Eclipse setup, then yes.  I did not modify the standard setup to use ProGuard, but it may be enabled by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok , so from my work with dex2jar I'd recomment running it directly on the apk file not on the classes.dex . So in your terminal ( using Windows in the exmple )

C:\dex2jar.bat Lost_apk.apk

It will spit out a jar file which you can look into with jd-gui.

Answer (score 1):

Got same issue in windows, solved - path must not contain special symbols, like '!', otherwise utility can't find libraries

Answer (score 0):

I'm on mac 10.13.1
I just had this issue.
I solve it by `chmod 700 lib` cause jar libs in it were not accessible.